# Python cx_Freeze Import Error "No module named humanize"

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>py C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\RPGTxtGame\setup.py build
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\RPGTxtGame\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    cx_Freeze.setup( name = "downloads", version = "1.0", options = {"build_exe": {"packages": ["errno", "os", "re", "stat", "subprocess","collections", "pprint","shutil", "humanize","pycallgraph"], "include_files": []}}, executables = exe )
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 621, in Freeze
    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 340, in _GetModuleFinder
    finder.IncludePackage(name)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 653, in IncludePackage
    module = self._ImportModule(name, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 350, in _ImportModule
    raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name)
ImportError: No module named 'humanize'
```

Hi, I tried to create an executable from my python project. cx_Freeze is givinig this error though

I also tried the [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) but that one is not compatible with python 3.6

My setup.py script is

```
import cx_Freeze

exe = [cx_Freeze.Executable("main.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup( name = "downloads", version = "1.0", options = {"build_exe": {"packages": ["errno", "os", "re", "stat", "subprocess","collections", "pprint","shutil", "humanize","pycallgraph"], "include_files": []}}, executables = exe )
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Do you have a module named humanize?

Comment: No I didnt import it, but neither did I import the other packages stated in the setup.exe

Comment: I'm guessing you may have to install humanize first. You probably have the other packages already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["errno", "os", "re", "stat", "subprocess","collections", "pprint","shutil", "humanize","pycallgraph"]}

setup( name = "downloads", 
       version = "1.0", 
       options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options}, 
       description = "Your description here.",
       executables = [Executable("main.py")])
```

As a side note depending on your environment you shouldn't need to explicitly include things like "os", "re", "shutil" or any other standard library modules as cx_Freeze should be able to find and import those automatically.

Also make sure your "humanize" package is imported in your "main.py" script.

Comment: Okay so I installed all the packages it requested, after humanize I ended up installing pycallgraph as well. Now it says that there is no such file/directory 'main.py'. Althought setup.py and main.py are in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed by avoiding the setup.py completely.

There is another way in the [Official documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/script.html)

Typing..

```
cxfreeze main.py
```

in the cmd works for me